# Is there a way to create actionable notifications on the Apple Watch without creating an actual watch app?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, usernotifications

I am trying to get an actionable notification for iOS app and watch app the actionable notification works on iOS and it shows on the watch as well when phone is locked. My issue is that in the watch it doesn't show the actions for the notification. I've read apple documentation and seems to create an app so I can customize the notification and make it actionable, is there a way to do this without an actual watch app is I don't require one neither want to develop/support one.

This is what I found in Apple's docs:

> Apps are not required to do anything to support notifications. The system provides a default notification interface that displays the alert message from the notification. However, apps can customize the notification interface and include custom graphics, content, and branding.

I read the Apple docs and some tutorials on how to customize the notification for the watchOS, but they require me to make an actual app.

I want the same actionable notification showing on the iOS app in the watch without a watch app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment on the previous answer as my rep points are too low, but I'm not entirely sure it's correct - you get actionnable notifications from WhatsApp or Slack without a watch app. (I don't know how to do them however which is why this should be a comment and not an answer, sorry).

Comment: oh I figure it out, yes you do get actionable notifications without a watch app I saw in code that if u remove the option to open the app when tapping on any action then you ll see them on the watch too and perform whatever logic you added to the action. thanks tho :D

Answer (score 0):

By design, an `actionable` notification means there should be a block of logic ( on the watch ) which should correctly handle your specified actions.

Therefore, you cannot do this without an app. Think of the "Reply" action ( which is custom ) for Telegram as an example. In order to have that action there, the watch must know what to do with it first and where to send that data back ( callback ). Hence, the need of an app.

Regards!

Comment: Thanks you for the quick reply! will it work to have a watch app and just have the logic for the action but just leave the app empty or showing some message like "redirect to the iOS app for more detail" since I just want the logic for the action but I don't really need a watch app

Comment: No probs buddy. Don't forget to accept the answer, so the question doesn't pop in unanswered.